# Error code ''int' object has no attribute '_create'' in Tkinter

Tags: tkinter

Here is my current code, I cannot figure out how to solve this error code, help would be appreciated :)

```
#imports
import random
from tkinter import *

#defining variables
chordTypes = ["Maj","Min","Dim","Aug","+7","+6","+4","+9","+11"] #9 values
notes = ["C", "C#/Db", "D", "D#/Eb", "E", "F", "F#/Gb", "G", "G#/Ab", "A", "A#/Bb", "B",] #12       values
guiList = []
initialChordSequence = []
top = Tk()
top.geometry("1000x500")

#generating the sequence randomly
for a in range(random.randint(3,7)):
    initialChordSequence.append((random.choice(notes))+(random.choice(chordTypes)))

#gui
root = Canvas(top, bg = "DarkOrange2", height = "500", width = "1400")
for b in range(12):
    guiList.append(b*100 + 100)
print(guiList)
for c in range(12):
    Canvas.create_rectangle(guiList[c], 150, guiList[c], 350)
root.pack()
top.mainloop()

#outputs
print(initialChordSequence)`
```

Tried to create 12 rectangles in tkinter with the dimensions defined by a values from a list. I ended up with the error code

Answer (score -1):

The problem is this line:

```
Canvas.create_rectangle(guiList[c], 150, guiList[c], 350)
```

You are trying to call `create_rectangle` on a class, rather than an instance of the class. You must call `create_rectangle` on an instance of a class.

In this case you've use the variable `root` to represent the canvas, so you need to call `root.create_rectangle`:

```
root.create_rectangle(guiList[c], 150, guiList[c], 350)
```

I strongly encourage you to use a different name. By convention, `root` is used to represent the root of the widget structure (ie: the result of creating an instance of `Tk`). Using `root` the way you do works, but it makes your code more confusing.